# Block hosts on non-rooted Android KitKat+

Tags: android, networking, dns, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm looking for a way how to reconfigure DNS to block a set of sites (like acme.com) which would be done using hosts file on Linux/Windows. However, my Android isn't rooted (thus it is not writable for me on Android). I would be fine if it would be working for all browser apps on the system.

I don't want to solve it by installing an antivirus vendor parental control app that require all system permissions.

Rather I'm looking for a simpler way OR open source app OR an app I could write myself so that I know what exactly it does.

Comment: I solved my problem by installing Firefox for Android with Minimal Site Block plug-in.